# Tikz surface plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot, wolfram-mathematica

Does anyone know how to replicate this *Mathematica* plot in tikz?
(*If possible: I'd like to use "pattern=crosshatched dots" to fill in the shaded region.*)

**Below is the *Mathematica* code:**

```
Show[(*Arrows- Top*) Graphics3D[{Black,Arrowheads[0.05],Arrow[Tube[{{0,.5,1},{1.1,.5,1}},.01]],Text[Style["\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(\[Epsilon]\), \(+\)]\)",Medium],{0,.5,1.1}]},Boxed->False,Axes->False,Background->None,Lighting->"Neutral",Ticks->None],Graphics3D[{Black,Arrowheads[0.05],Arrow[Tube[{{0,.25,1},{1.1,.25,1}},.01]], Text[Style["\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(\[Epsilon]\), \(-\)]\)",Medium],{0,.25,1.1}]}], (*Arrows-Bottom*) Graphics3D[{Black,Arrowheads[0.05],Arrow[Tube[{{0,.25,0},{1.1,.25,0}},.01]], Text[Style["\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(\[Epsilon]\), \(-\)]\)",Medium],{1.2,.25,0}]}],Graphics3D[{Black,Arrowheads[0.05],Arrow[Tube[{{0,.5,0},{1.1,.5,0}},.01]],Text[Style["\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(\[Epsilon]\), \(+\)]\)",Medium],{1.2,.5,0}]}],(*x-Axes*) Graphics3D[{Black,Arrowheads[0.07],Arrow[Tube[{{0,1,0},{1.3,1,0}},.01]], Text[Style["x",Medium],{1.35,1,0}]}],(*y-Axes*) Graphics3D[{Black,Arrowheads[0.07],Arrow[Tube[{{0,1,0},{0,-.35,0}},.01]],Text[Style["y",Medium],{0,-.5,0}]}], (*y-Axes*) Graphics3D[{Black,Arrowheads[0.07],Arrow[Tube[{{0,1,0},{0,1,1.3}},.01]],Text[Style["n",Medium],{0,1,1.35}]}],(*Surface*) Plot3D[Sqrt[1-x^2],{x,0,1},{y,0,1},Axes->True,AxesLabel->{"x","y","n"},Boxed->False,PlotStyle->Directive[Gray,Opacity[0.5]],Mesh->None,Background->None,Lighting->"Neutral"], (*Epsilon above surface*) RegionPlot3D[Sqrt[1-x^2]<= z,{x,0,1},{y,.25,.5},{z,0,1},PlotStyle->None],RegionPlot3D[ .25<= y<=.5,{x,0,1},{y,.25,.5},{z,-.01,.01},PlotStyle->None]]
```

[image: Image renderered in *Mathematica*]

[image: The red represents the volume to be filled with dots]

Comment: Are you asking for fun or there are any technical issue preventing you from `\includegraphics`?  Please aware that questions looks like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are either "off topic", "too broad", or "unclear". Please try to give a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) showing how much you have done yet. you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

Comment: @Symbol1 **Technical issue:** How to make curved 3D function with patterns and fill region plots with patterns. After many failed attempts I switched to Mathematica to create a MWE to submit to the forum.  

**My 2 cents:**
From the perspective of a first time user, wouldn’t it make sense to have a template submission form that outlined the particular criterion the forum is looking for? Rather than waste a lot of time and energy on responses such as these?

Comment: The point is to make the asker to clarify his/her problem. Sometimes there do exists just-for-fun problem but we cannot image that there are 100 such problems per day. Besides, the  less you are asking for, the shorter/clearer the code will be. For example, Mathematica draws you beautiful 3D arrows. Do you like such arrows? The cylinder is shaded, is it necessary? As a contrast, you mentioned only `pattern=crosshatched dots` so Ignasi *forget*, probably deliberately, the `pattern=grid` part.

Comment: By the way, you may yell that **WHO cares about ARROWS, I want OOXXOOX**. But Please remember, **we just do not konw**. Ti*k*Z devotes a library to arrow tips so... nothing is impossible and everything is important.

Comment: @Symbol1 I apologize for taking so long to respond. my computer broke. Thanks for the response and clarification. The example is for me to visualize concepts in real analysis. I will try to be clearer and more specific w/ questions in the future.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[->] (0,0,0)--++(5,0,0) node[right]{$x$};
\draw[->] (0,0,0)--++(0,5,0) node[above]{$n$};
\draw[->] (0,0,0)--++(0,0,5) node[below left]{$y$};
\draw (0,4,0) arc[start angle=90, end angle=0, radius=4] -- ++(0,0,4.5)
arc[start angle=0, end angle=90, radius=4]--cycle;
\draw[thick, pattern=crosshatch dots] (0,4,1.5) arc[start angle=90, end angle=0, radius=4] -- ++(0,0,1.5)
arc[start angle=0, end angle=90, radius=4]--cycle;
\draw[->, thick] (0,0,1.5)--++(4.5,0,0) node[right]{$\epsilon^+$};
\draw[->, thick] (0,0,3)--++(4.5,0,0) node[right]{$\epsilon^-$};
\draw[->, thick] (0,4,1.5)--++(4.5,0,0) node[right]{$\epsilon^+$};
\draw[->, thick] (0,4,3)--++(4.5,0,0) node[right]{$\epsilon^-$};
\draw[thick, pattern=crosshatch dots] (0,4,1.5)--++(4,0,0)--++(0,0,1.5)--++(-4,0,0)--cycle;
\draw[thick, pattern=crosshatch dots] (4,0,1.5)--++(0,4,0)--++(0,0,1.5)--++(0,-4,0)--cycle;
\draw[thick, pattern=crosshatch dots] (0,0,1.5)--++(4,0,0)--++(0,0,1.5)--++(-4,0,0)--cycle;
\draw[thick, pattern=crosshatch dots] (0,0,1.5)--++(0,4,0)--++(0,0,1.5)--++(0,-4,0)--cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Let's try again:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
%axis
\draw[->] (0,0,0)--++(5,0,0) node[right]{$x$};
\draw[->] (0,0,0)--++(0,5,0) node[above]{$n$};
\draw[->] (0,0,0)--++(0,0,5) node[below left]{$y$};

%curved surface
\draw (0,4,0) arc[start angle=90, end angle=0, radius=4] -- 
    ++(0,0,4.5) arc[start angle=0, end angle=90, radius=4]--cycle;

%internal curved surface        
\draw[thick] (0,4,1.5) arc[start angle=90, end angle=0, radius=4] -- 
           ++(0,0,1.5) arc[start angle=0, end angle=90, radius=4]--cycle;

%Epsilon arrows
\draw[->, thick] (0,0,1.5)--++(4.5,0,0) node[right]{$\epsilon^+$};
\draw[->, thick] (0,0,3)--++(4.5,0,0) node[right]{$\epsilon^-$};
\draw[->, thick] (0,4,1.5)--++(4.5,0,0) node[right]{$\epsilon^+$};
\draw[->, thick] (0,4,3)--++(4.5,0,0) node[right]{$\epsilon^-$};

%vertical epsilon delimited area
\draw[thick] (4,0,1.5)--++(0,4,0)--++(0,0,1.5)--++(0,-4,0)--cycle;

%horizontal hatched rectangle
\draw[thick, pattern=crosshatch dots] (0,0,1.5)--++(4,0,0)--++(0,0,1.5)--++(-4,0,0)--cycle;

%hatched volume
\draw[thick, pattern=crosshatch dots] (0,4,1.5)--++(0,0,1.5) 
     arc[start angle=90, end angle=0, radius=4] --++(0,0,-1.5)--++(0,4,0)--++(-4,0,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! You rock! One question: How do I fill the region between the "top of the curve" and "the epsilon boundaries" w/ the crosshatched pattern? Regardless, thank you for your help it is much appreciated.

Comment: @BarrettLeslie Figure updated. Is what you want?

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to get back. My computer died. Answer: Not exactly.I'm wanting to "fill the volume" w/ dots between the rectangular surface and the top of the curve. i.e. I want to fill the "red region" w/ dots in the image I posted above.

Comment: @BarrettLeslie Updated again. Is it better?

Comment: Yes, that's it exactly. Thank you so much. This will help me w/ other volumes I would like to fill w/ patterns as well!

Comment: The accepted (wonderful) solution draws the figure with a technical viewpoint, which does not look "naturally". (orthographic vs. perspective projection) The Mathematica image looks more naturally, therefore I would like to add the possibility that you could use [Sketch](http://www.frontiernet.net/~eugene.ressler/). Disclaimer: I have no personal experience with this program.